# evaluating value of a function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function

Is it possible to do like this in matlab in a single .m file
like defining a function f(x)=e^x-x^2;
and using f(x) to find f(2)

```
f(x)=e^x-x^2;
f(2);
```

I tried this but it is showing an error undefined variable 'x'

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html

Comment: Is it possible to do this without including functions ? @Marc B

Comment: thnx a lot everyone :) I figured it out

Comment: You can do this using lambda expressions/anonymous functions `f = @(x)exp(x)-x^2` then you can evaluate `f(2)`. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Answer (score -2):

The "matlabic" way of doing things is to have each function be a .m file, so you would have one f.m file.  If this file is in the current matlab directory or on the matlab path, you can then call f(2) in the interactive window, or *realtime interpreter* and see the result.

Comment: No no no no no "*matlabic*" please. Hell no.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Matlabaceous? Matlabean? Matlabatic? Matlabistic? Matlatbillistic? Matlaboid? Matlaboodean? Matlabtastic? Matlabillicious?